# Apache: How to give a path its own URL?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

This should be simple, but I can't get it to work.

I have a site with a path in it, like this: `www.mysite.com/coolstuff`. When a user types `www.coolstuff.com` I want Apache to go to `www.mysite.com/coolstuff`.

A possible complication is that `coolstuff` is not in the docroot, but I'm using an alias to point to its directory. So `coolstuff` is not really a subdirectory within the mysite.com docroot. I'm hoping that has nothing to do with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple, you just need to set up a separate virtual host for www.coolstuff.com. If you use name-based virtual hosting (the most common configuration, in which you have a `NameVirtualHost *:80` directive somewhere in the config file), you can do this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.coolstuff.com
    ServerAlias coolstuff.com
    RedirectPermanent / http://www.mysite.com/coolstuff/
</VirtualHost>
```

This would redirect the browser to `www.mysite.com/coolstuff`, i.e. the user would know they're getting sent to a different URL. If you'd rather not have that, it would probably be easier to just make the coolstuff directory a document root of its own:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.coolstuff.com
    ServerAlias coolstuff.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/coolstuff
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You rule!  Thanks very much.  I went with the DocumentRoot (second) approach and it's perfection.